# Unable to remove advertising from Dash searches because of lack of "Security" item in System Settings

Tags: 14.04, unity-dash, system-settings

Ubuntu 14.04 on Dell Optiplex GX520.  Launchpad suggested reinstalling System Settings, but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable Internet searches in the dash by clicking "Filter results" in the top-right corner of the dash and deselecting all the sources you don't want.